# Unexpected Nesting of Parenthesis:610

Tags: z3

I am trying to use the Z3 windows binary with an input file, but I always get an error in the last line of the file, which says 'Unexpected Nesting of Parenthesis:610'.
Kindly help

Comment: Which version are you using? Could you post a link to the input file?

Comment: I downloaded the binary just hours before posting this question. So it must be the latest version. The input file can be accessed at:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezyrz98556lblhy/rural.z3

Comment: Hi, I have realized that I should save the file with .smt2 extension. It's working fine now. Thanks for the support